# Add test on the new custom attributes magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom

I added 3 new attributes: Personnal Contact must be just with letter else an exception will be displayed and Website must be valid and Tel must be Numerique so how to do that please

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that your attributes are customer types of attributes.

For manage and create customer attributes you can download this extension from market place.

https://marketplace.magento.com/clarion-customer-attribute.html

Or you can also refer magento default validation classes and set it as per your requirement.

lib/web/mage/validation.js

Comment: i want to understand the second option how to override the validation.js and ho wto use it please give me an example

Comment: You can get reference from this blog.  

https://inchoo.net/magento-2/validate-custom-form-in-magento-2/